# Framework for python with sqlite

Tags: python, frameworks, sqlite

i am new in python.before this i done some work in php with codeigniter framework.

now i want to develop website using python and sqlite3.
so which framework will you suggest me.
i also want to know IDE for sqlite.

Comment: An IDE for SQLite. You're funny.

Comment: @lgnacio i use the WAMPSERVER in php which provide IDE for Mysql. so like that any app is available for python and sqlite?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers I googled it out but I havent used it ever

Comment: For your "IDE" question I invite you to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403/is-there-a-good-ide-for-sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something similar to [sqliteman](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/) or [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)? These are not not IDEs for SQLite, but instead, are GUI interfaces. There are more here: http://www.google.com/search?&q=sqlite+gui

3rd link down is another stack overflow question: [What are good open source GUI SQLite database managers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers)

For Python web frameworks, a very popular full-stack framework is the [Django Project](http://www.djangoproject.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/). It's a feature-rich full-stack framework, but it's also very easy to set up, learn, and use. It requires no installation or configuration, has no dependencies, and includes its own web server and web-based IDE/administrative interface (see [demo](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/default/site)). If you download the binary version for Windows or Mac, it even includes its own Python interpreter (so you don't need to have Python installed).

The [database abstraction layer](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06) (DAL) works with 10 different database backends, including SQLite. It doesn't include its own SQLite IDE, though it does include a database administrative interface called [appadmin](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/03#More-on-appadmin), which allows you to view all database tables; view, insert, update, and delete records within each table; and import/export tables to CSV. You can also import and export the entire database to CSV. (Note, these features work for all database backends, not just SQLite.)

You will probably also find that you don't really need an IDE for SQLite when using web2py because the DAL takes care of everything for you. You specify all of your data models using the DAL syntax, and then the DAL automatically creates the SQLite database, creates all tables, and handles [migrations](http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Migrations) when you changes your models.

If you have any questions, there's a friendly and responsive [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py) that will provide lots of help.